# Logging over the wire?

Tags: c++, linux, logging

We have cases wherein we write a lot of log files to the host increasing the i/o on a host. Are there any good open source logging over the wire solutions.

The application language is C++ on Red Hat Linux 3.

Comment: Are you sure it's Redhat 3, not Redhat Enterprise 3?

According to my guess, Redhat 3 is at least 11 years old.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple logging option is to use syslog and rely on (after correct configuration) the syslog daemon to forward it to a remote server.

Take a look at:

`openlog()`

`syslog()`

`closelog()`

and:

`syslog.conf`

Answer (score 1):

There are logging libraries that can help you. depending on your application language. But if i/o is a problem probably network bandwidth is a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

First set of questions:

- Do you need all those log files?
- All the time?
- Can you control how much logging occurs?
- Why not?

Second set of questions:

- Why are your log writing operations slow?
- Are you using inappropriate operations (for example, O_SYNC or related options on POSIX)?
- How many disk drives do you have?
- Can you gain by having different log files on different drives (or, at least, having the log files on a different drive from where the other files are stored)?

As @igalse says, there are logging libraries available.  For C++, you should look at what is available at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), but there are undoubtedly other sources too.

Answer (score 1):

For C++, Boost doesn't contain a library for logging yet. But you can use the most advanced candidate, written by John Torjo, [here](http://torjo.com/log2/doc/html/index.html).

It allows to filter some of your logging (you probably need that, if the logging is so important that it becomes a performance problem) and setting different destinations, like a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If the I/O on the host is being impacted unnecessarily, then in my opinion you are either:

- Doing FAR too much logging - logging sufficiently that it approaches IO write speed on a sustained basis is probably too much - as even the most modest hardware can comfortably do several megabytes per second without a problem
- Doing too many flushes of your logs - this is more likely. Syslogd flushes the log quite a lot by default (too much for log-intensive applications) - this is so that log files are durable in the event of a crash - but generates a lot of IOs. Syslogd can be reconfigured on a per-file basis (see its man page) not to flush the files out so often.

Logging to a network server isn't going to solve these problems if it has the same issue - in fact, it will make them worse if several hosts are logging to the same server.

Answer (score -1):

The application language is C++ on Red Hat Linux 3.

Comment: I've added this information to the question, kal; I suggest you remove this answer.